# How to display in shiny app a matrix, specifying the color with conditionals?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a matrix M with positive values and negative values. I am trying to display as a table in shiny app, using the DT package. I would like to display the matrix with different colors. Positive numbers in red and negative numbers (for example).

So far, I only can add colours in a one-to-one way . But I want to add colours in this way: if matrix_values > 0 "color1", if matrix_values < 0 "color2".

```
 M <- matrix(c(-3:2), 3) # The matrix is more complex and it's created in a 
 reactive environment. Here is only an example

 M_out <- reactive({

 DT::datatable(M()) %>% 
   formatStyle(
     columns = c(1:7),
     backgroundColor = styleEqual(c( 0, 1), c("green", "red")
   ))
 })
 output$X_table_2 <- DT::renderDataTable(M_1X2())
```

Thanks !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DT::styleInterval` instead of `DT::styleEqual`

```
library(DT)      # for datatable, formatStyle, styleInterval
library(dplyr)   # for %>%

myDT <- matrix(c(-3:2), 3) %>% datatable %>% 
  formatStyle(
    columns = 1:2,
    backgroundColor = styleInterval( 
      cuts = c(-.01, 0), 
      values = c("red", "white", "green")
    )
  )

myDT
```

Runnig these lines in RStudio will display the formatted matrix in the viewer pane. If you are not using RStudio, you can also show the table in a shiny app.

```
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(DT::dataTableOutput('table'))
  server = function(input, output, session){
    output$table = DT::renderDataTable({myDT})
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. It works okay. Let me ask another question. Actually, I am trying to display a matrix  X with dimension equal to M. Instead of display M, I would like to display the matrix X, not M. It means: * color1 in cells of X  where M > 0 (X[M>0]) , color2 in cells of X where M<0 (X[M<0]) and color3 in cells of X where M == 0 (X[M == 0])*. Is it possible do in a simple way? Thanks !!!

Comment: Yes, this is possible, but not very straightforward. You can add the columns of M as hidden columns to the table and use them as `valueColumns` in `formatStyle`.

Comment: I just updated the answer to discuss how to fromat a matrix X according to another matrix M.