# How to display in shiny app a matrix A with cell color depending of the cells of another matrix B?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I have a matrix **M** with positive values and negative values. I have another matrix **X** (dim(X) = dim(M)). I am trying to display **X** as a table in shiny app, using the DT package. I would like to display the matrix **X** with different colors conditioned by the values of **M**.  It means: *color1 in cells of X where M > 0 (X[M>0]) , color2 in cells of X where M<0 (X[M<0]) and color3 in cells of X where M == 0 (X[M == 0])*.

The next code shows where I got stuck:
        X <- matrix(c(1:9), 3)
        M <- matrix(c(-3:2), 3) # The matrix is more complex and it's created in a 
        reactive environment. Here is only an example

```
         X_colors <- reactive({

             DT::datatable(X()) %>% 
               formatStyle(
               columns = c(1:3),
               valueColumns(¿How do reference to M matrix?),
               backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(-1,0), c("lightgreen", 
               "lightred", "lightblue")
             ))
           })
          output$X_table_2 <- DT::renderDataTable(X_colors())
```

thanks !!

Comment: The solution is here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365197/how-to-display-in-shiny-app-a-matrix-specifying-the-color-with-conditionals

Comment: Ah! I didn't notice you created a new question. I'll move the solution you linked to to this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you ask for is possible but not very straightforward. My approach includes using hidden columns. My "recipe":

1. `cbind` the "conditions-matrix" **M** and the "values-matrix" **X**,
2. Hide the columns belonging to the conditions-matrix using the `options` argument in `datatable`.
3. Set the hidden columns as `valueColumns` and the non-hidden columns as `columns` in `DT::formatStyle`

---

```
library(DT)
library(dplyr)   # for %>%

print(M <- matrix(c(-3:2), 3))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,]   -3    0
# [2,]   -2    1
# [3,]   -1    2
print(X <- matrix(letters[1:6], 3))
#      [,1] [,2]
# [1,] "a"  "d" 
# [2,] "b"  "e" 
# [3,] "c"  "f"

cbind(M, X) %>% datatable(
  options = list(columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE, targets = 0:1)))
) %>%
  formatStyle(
    columns = 3:4,
    valueColumns = 1:2,
    backgroundColor = styleInterval(c(-.01, 0), c("red", "white", "green"))
  )
```

Notice that I used `targets = 0:1` to hide columns `1:2` since this parameter follows javascript syntax where indexing begins with `0` rather than `1`.

[image]