# Format row with color in DataTable with JavaScript

Tags: shiny, colors, dt

how do I modify the code in this thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55657754/how-to-color-the-background-of-a-cell-in-datatable-dt-package-in-r-with-column) to apply the color format to the entire row, not just a particular cell?

Particularly, this one:

```
changeCellColor <- function(row, col){
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  if(index == %d){", row-1),
    sprintf("    $('td:eq(' + %d + ')', row)", col),
    "    .css({'background-color': 'orange'});",
    "  }",
    "}"  
  )
}
datatable(dat, 
          options = list(
            dom = "t",
            rowCallback = JS(changeCellColor(1, 2))
          )
)
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
changeCellColor <- function(row){
  c(
    "function(row, data, num, index){",
    sprintf("  if(index == %d){", row-1),
    "for(n = 0; n <= 4; n++) {",
    "  $('td:eq(' + n + ')', row)",
    "    .css({'background-color': 'orange'});",
    "}",
    "  }",
    "}"  
  )
}
datatable(dat, 
          options = list(
            dom = "t",
            rowCallback = JS(changeCellColor(1))
          )
)
```